# Create Functional Linux GUI Using Vulkan Without X11

Tags: linux, user-interface, x11, vulkan

I'd like to create my own user interface that would run on a bare-bones Linux distribution. The GUI would be rendered using Vulkan and my hope is to get user input without X11. The GUI would immediately render after the OS loads and be the main context.

**Questions**:

- What are the implications in doing this?
- How would I obtain user input?
- How could I configure my GUI application to correctly load?
- Is Vulkan not ideal for this type of scenario?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's too bad I can't answer.  Here is an example: https://bitbucket.org/cheako/vkwayland/src/master/src/fbcon/vulkanio.cpp

Comment: @MikeMestnik What are the dependencies of that? I couldn't find what ECM is and it's asking for it

Comment: Here is an example build script: https://bitbucket.org/cheako/vkwayland/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Comment: @Tooniis Better use the bitbucket issue tracking system...  So u can post things like logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the implications in doing this?

Vulkan is by design headless. At the minimum you can render something in it and then copy it out to raw bytes (i.e. using `vkMapMemory`). With the help of [`VK_KHR_external_*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_KHR_external_memory_fd) extensions you can even do something like that more efficiently (in 0-copy way).

Vulkan is only a rendering API though. It is **not** a *windowing system*. It is **not** a competitor to X11 (or Wayland, or Mir, or Whatever). Doing something like that would mean using alternative like Wayland (if your beef is specifically with X11) or implement your own.

> How would I obtain user input?

Also outside of the scope of Vulkan. Again, probably means reimplementing something like X11.

> How could I configure my GUI application to correctly load?

If you mean existing apps, you would have to modify existing infrastructure to also accept and use your new window manager beside the ubiquitous X11.

If you mean new apps, then that is specific to the window manager API you intend to create, isn't it?

> Is Vulkan not ideal for this type of scenario?

It is probably fine for this scenario (probably more so than OpenGL ever was). But it is also probably the easiest aspect of this idea. The hard part is all the things Vulkan does **not** do and year(s) necessary to re-implement that wheel.

Comment: Where should I look for information about rendering Vulkan with DRM? I can't find decent learning-material on it through Google. I have managed to find a few projects that use it, just nothing that explains how it works.

Comment: @Scetra The [kernel docs](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/gpu/index.html), I guess. AIS the Vulkan part is relatively straightforward aspect of this and reading the [Vulkan spec(and the relevant extensions)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_KHR_external_memory_fd) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because that's not how Vulkan works.

On Linux, Vulkan is a substitute for OpenGL, not for X11. (Similarly, on Windows it substitutes for DirectX or OpenGL, not the [Desktop Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager).)

Comment: I'm not trying to actually substitute Vulkan and X11. Rather make 'my own X11', if you will. Instead of extending X11 (like a lot of distros do), I'd like to create my own rendering environment. Something that doesn't depend on X. I'd like to use the Vulkan API to do said rendering. Perhaps I need to remove the correlation between X as it makes my question confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change the answer. The Vulkan drivers that are available on Linux are for X11. They cannot be used without it.

Comment: Interesting. I found this project: [link](https://github.com/datenwolf/kmscube) that does indeed use headless rendering (OpenGL). I've been browsing Reddit as well and people have been saying that you can do the same with Vulkan?

Comment: That is interesting -- it looks like they're using the DRM (Direct Rendering Manager, not Digital Rights Management) modules directly. Still, I wouldn't count on the same trick working for Vulkan…

Comment: It does: [project](https://github.com/krh/vkcube). Note: this project contains support for X and Wayland in addition to DRM.

Comment: This is not true... anymore.  Vulkan on Linux does support fbcon https://bitbucket.org/cheako/vkwayland/src/master/src/fbcon/vulkanio.cpp